# How can I Wrap contents inside some html tag without affecting any html tag using Regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I'm parsing a block of text through a regex pattern and I need to wrap the resultant text within a `span` tag.

I am usign this library  http://xregexp.com/

The siblings of the text may or may not contain tags.

Example Input:

```
<span><span>T</span><span>e</span><span><span>st</span></span>  <b>1</b> </span> . <i>2</i>
```

From the above input, I got the text using jQuery getText() and parsed into the pattern.

```
((?<first>\\b[Tt][Ee][Ss]([A-z]{0,3})?)(?<one>(\.?\\s?))(?<Numberone>[0-9]{0,3}?)(?<two>(\.?\\s?\-?))(?<NumberTwo>[0-9]{0,3}))';
```

I'm using XRegExp 4.2.0 Library.

Output from regex :

```
 first : Test
 Numberone : 1 
 NumberTwo : 2
```

What I'm trying to achieve: `<span id="test"><span>T</span><span>e</span><span><span>st</span></span><span> 
<span id="1"><span> <b>1</b> </span></span> .
<span id="2"> <i>2</i></span>`

I can't think of a suitable logic to execute it using Jquery.

Appreciate any Help. Thanks !

Comment: HTML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.

Comment: @Toto Thanks for your reply when I use parser shall I get the mentioned output?